# Python script to sum values according to conditions in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, python-itertools

I need to sum the value contained in a column (column 9) if a condition is satisfied: the condition is that it needs to be a pair of individuals (column 1 and column 3), whether they are repeated or not.

My input file is made this way:

```
Sindhi_HGDP00171    0   Tunisian_39T    0   1   120437718   147097266   3.02    7.111
Sindhi_HGDP00183    1   Sindhi_HGDP00206    2   1   242708729   244766624   7.41    3.468
Sindhi_HGDP00183    1   Sindhi_HGDP00206    2   1   242708729   244766624   7.41    4.468
IBS_HG01768 2   Moroccan_MRA46  1   1   34186193    36027711    30.46   3.108
IBS_HG01710 1   Sardinian_HGDP01065 2   1   246117191   249120684   7.53    3.258
IBS_HG01768 2   Moroccan_MRA46  2   1   34186193    37320967    43.4    4.418
```

Therefore for instance, I would need the value of column 9 for each pair to be summed. Some of these pairs appear multiple time, in this case I would need the sum of value in column 9 betweem IBS_HG01768 and Moroccan_MRA46, and the sum of the value between Sindhi_HGDP00183 and Sindhi_HGDP00206. Some of these pairs are not repeated but I still need them to appear in the final results.

What I manage so far is to sum by group (population), so I sum column 9 value by pair of population like Sindhi and Tunisian for instance. I need to do the sum by pairs of Individuals.

My script is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
 
# defines columns names
cols = ['ID1', 'HAP1', 'ID2', 'HAP2', 'CHR', 'STARTPOS', 'ENDPOS', 'LOD', 'IBDLENGTH']
 
# loads data (the file needs to be in the same folder where the script is)
data = pd.read_csv("./Roma_Ref_All_sorted.txt", sep = '\t', names = cols)

# removes the sample ID for ID1/ID2 columns and places it in two dedicated columns
data[['ID1', 'ID1_samples']] = data['ID1'].str.split('_', expand = True)
data[['ID2', 'ID2_samples']] = data['ID2'].str.split('_', expand = True)

# gets the groups list from both ID columns...
groups_id1 = list(data.ID1.unique()) 
groups_id2 = list(data.ID2.unique())
groups = list(set(groups_id1 + groups_id2))
# ... and all the possible pairs 
group_pairs = [i for i in itertools.combinations(groups, 2)]
# subsets the pairs having Roma
group_pairs_roma = [x for x in group_pairs if ('Roma' in x[0] and x[0] != 'Romanian') or 
                    ('Roma' in x[1] and x[1] != 'Romanian')]

# preapres output df
result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'IBD_sum'])
 
# loops all the possible pairs and computes the sum of IBD length
for idx, group_pair in enumerate(group_pairs_roma):
    id1 = group_pair[0]
    id2 = group_pair[1]
    ibd_sum = round(data.loc[((data['ID1'] == id1) & (data['ID2'] == id2)) |
                              ((data['ID1'] == id2) & (data['ID2'] == id1)), 'IBDLENGTH'].sum(),3)
    result.loc [idx, ['ID1', 'ID2', 'IBD_sum']] = [id1, id2, ibd_sum]
 
# saves results
result.to_csv("./groups_pairs_sum_IBD.txt", sep = '\t', index = False)
```

My current output is something like this:

```
ID1 ID2 IBD_sum
Sindhi  IBS 3.275
Sindhi  Moroccan    74.201
Sindhi  Sindhi  119.359
```

While I need something like:

```
ID1 ID2 IBD_sum
Sindhi_individual1 Moroccan_individual1 3.275
Sindhi_individual2 Moroccan_individual2 5.275
Sindhi_individual3  IBS_individual1 4.275
```

I have tried by substituting one line in my code, by writing

```
groups_id1 = list(data.ID1_samples.unique()) 
groups_id2 = list(data.ID2_samples.unique())
```

and later

```
ibd_sum = round(data.loc[((data['ID1_samples'] == id1) & (data['ID2_samples'] == id2)) |
                              ((data['ID1_samples'] == id2) & (data['ID2_samples'] == id1)), 'IBDLENGTH'].sum(),3)
```

Which in theory should work because I set the individuals as pairs instead of populations as pairs, but the output was empty. What could I do to edit the code for what I need?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you want your question to be answered more quickly, it's always best to try and make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way, your question is more useful to you (quicker response), the reviewers (easier to answer) and future readers (more likely to fit their scenario).

Comment: I have already posted a minimal reproducible example, as my files in reality contain hundreds of thousands of lines. But I wouldn't know how to reduce the script itself without omitting important details of what I need it to do

Comment: Looks like there are 6 out of your 9 columns of data that are unused in this question. That is not minimal. You are for example not using the `STARTPOS` column anywhere but still adding it in your question, which just adds noise onto your question. That makes it less likely to be answered properly and less likely to be useful for future readers (because it takes longer to read/understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem on my own but using R language.
This is the code:

```
ibd <- read.delim("input.txt", sep='\t')

ibd_sum_indv <- ibd %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  summarise(SIBD = sum(IBDLENGTH),
            NIBD = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```